# How to add multiple labels to a winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms

**Issue**
I have a simple ui, where user enters a value click on the "ok" button, the SubmitDateHandler click handler should then insert a label to the form  with the value from the textbox. Then when this is repeated again, Add another label underneath the existing label. how to dynamically add multiple labels in a new line?

my code, at the moment is able to add one label, but not the second one.

```
private void SubmitDatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label dateLabel = new Label();
        dateLabel.Text = this.Controls.Find("Datetxt", true)[0].Text + Environment.NewLine;
        this.LatestScoresPanel.Controls.Add(dateLabel);
    }
```

Comment: What is `LatestScoresPanel` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use [`FlowLayOutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx), you can specify either veritcal or horizontal layout with it. Add the label to that like:

```
this.flowLayOutPanel.Controls.Add(dataLabel);
```

Make sure to specify `FlowDirection` either in code or design time.

```
flowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
```